# Best way to replace an abstract class property callable from parent in C#

Tags: c#

In a lot of languages, you can override the value of a property of a class when extending an abstract class, and the parent methods will read this new variable when used, an example would be something like this:

```
abstract class A {
    protected string foo;
    
    void PrintFoo() {
        print(foo);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    protected string foo = "bar";
}

(new B()).PrintFoo(); // outputs: bar
```

In C# I haven't been able to find a standard way to do this, as this is not allowed.

One way I've found is by passing it by parent constructor like:

```
abstract class A {
    protected string foo;
    public A(string foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    void PrintFoo() {
        Console.WriteLine(foo);
    }
}

class B : A {
    public B() : A("bar") {}
}

(new B()).PrintFoo(); // outputs: bar
```

But clearly this is not clean at all.
Another way I've seen is by making a virtual string and overriding it later (which would be similar to the other languages):

```
abstract class A {
    protected virtual string Foo { get; }

    void PrintFoo() {
        Console.WriteLine(Foo);
    }
}

class B : A {
    protected override string Foo {
        get { return "bar"; }
    }
}

(new B()).PrintFoo(); // outputs: bar
```

It seems as to me the second way is the appropriate one, but it's not as clean as I expected.

Is there a better way?

**EDIT**

As @MakePeaceGreatAgain stated, there's a shorter way that even it is an arrow function and not a direct way to set the variable, it would be the shortest and most similar way as in another langs:

```
abstract class A
{
    public virtual string Foo => null;
}
class B : A
{
    public override string Foo => "bar";
}
```

Comment: Don’t have protected fields. Keep them private and access them through properties. Even abstract properties

Comment: @DanielA.White this is not the point of the question, I can do that but it won't reduce the boilerplate

Comment: Boilerplate is the way you tell the compiler the intent. That’s OOP for you

Comment: @DanielA.White this ain't true. This is another debate, but other languages allows you to replace field values from child classes. Imagine a Model class in which you wanna set the table name, it could be done with just overriding a field, no need for boilerplate.

It's just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't *override* a field, only methods (and properties and the like). In order to change a fields default-value, you can assign it in the derived class' constructor:

```
class B : A
{
    public B() { foo = "bar"; } // you have access to foo, as it's protected field
}
```

You should however make your field `readonly`, to avoid changing it after your instance was created.

Apart from this what you consider "not clean at all" is a really good solution, in my opinion, as it enables you to limit the access to the field even further to `private`:

```
class A
{
    private string foo;
    public A(string f) { this.foo = f; }
}
class B : A
{
    public B : A("bar") { }
}
```

This way not even `B` can access or manipulate the fields value. However it's pretty up to you if you need this kind of security.

Another way would be to wrap the field in a property and override that one:

```
class A
{
    public virtual string Foo => null;
}
class B : A
{
    public override string Foo => "bar";
}
```

I'd not say this is *per-se* better, as properties aren't per-se better than fields. If it were that simple, `public` or `prtoteced` fields probably were forbidden by the compiler (shouldn't be that hard to implement that). However exposing fields to the outside of your class makes it hard to keep track on when they change. That's whay people love properties, as they encapsulate the field to keep track on its changes. It's easy to validate the new value for a property. Doing that on a field can become a nighmare soon.

Comment: Got it, just wanted to know if C# allowed it via some keyword as other languages do. I know it's better to encapsulate like using getters/setters in other langs, and properties makes it easier. But in this case it is just a matter of defining a default value for that field, like imagine a class Aircraft and wanting to set the name, make, model, etc. from the child class.

I see the best option (or cleaner) would be with arrow functions and properties. Thank you!

Comment: Also the problem is that if I want to pass a lot of field values, the constructor would become too big. I could pass a struct but I want the fields to be part of the class, so it adds a lot of boilerplate or making the constructor big is not something I'd consider clean. That's why

Comment: @maduranma then go with the `protected readonly`-field. I would'nt bother about a big constructor, if all it does it initializing these fields. In fact your "clean approach" does also need one line of code per "override". So does the ctor-approach.